# Hospital Expenditure Dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, finance, spending

I am looking for a data set containing expenditures of hospital/medical facility, ideally day to day, containing detailed spending information on items, supplies and other costs.

Also, if there is patient data, at least a count of patients with the data, it will be ideal.

One hospital or facility would do but it will be great to have more than one.

Comment: do you need something other than https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/ ?

Comment: Please add this as an answer, but most of it requires permissions or is paid. I am looking for free datasets.